# Where are additional dependent children listed on the 2018 1040 tax form?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-credit, children

I was getting a head start on my taxes and wondering what form there is for listing out additional children.  On the old form, I attached another form (probably something just autogenerated by my freefile preparer) that was for my other children.  But I don't see any forms that are supposed to be added with additional children any more, what do you do when you're filling out the paper version of the new postcard 1040?

Comment: Do you remember the name of the schedule that you used in previous years?

Comment: @ben I guess it wasn't a "schedule" I used to use an online preparer and they made a form that said "Additional information from your Form 1040: Individual Tax Return" It would also lop off the 4th child and say "see Stmt" instead of listing her there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the new postcard-sized [2018 Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1040), there is a box that looks like this:

[image: more than four dependents checkbox]

The [2018 Form 1040 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm140021882108864) say this:

> If you have more than four dependents, check the box on the right side of page 1 of Form 1040 (just above the Dependents section) and include a statement showing the information required in columns (1) through (4).

It seems that, if you are submitting your taxes on paper, you simply attach an additional sheet of paper with the same information you supply for your first four dependents, namely the dependent's first and last name, social security number, relationship to you, and whether or not your dependent qualifies for the "Child tax credit" or the "Credit for other dependents."

I'm not aware of a form or schedule specifically for this, even in previous years. (Although, since I don't have more than four children, I don't have personal experience with this.)